# Second Text Composable not shown

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm following the courses on Android Compose available @ https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-composables-practice-problems?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-1-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-composables-practice-problems#2

I'm trying to implement the solution to problem #2, however, Compose won't render second Text Composable. Source code:

```kotlin
package com.example.taskmanager

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.taskmanager.ui.theme.TaskManagerTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TaskManagerTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    TaskManagerImage(status = stringResource(R.string.task_status_text),
                        message = stringResource(R.string.task_message_text)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TaskManagerText(status: String, message: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Text(
            text = status,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(top=24.dp, bottom=8.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = message,
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = modifier
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun TaskManagerImage(status: String, message: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val image = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_task_completed)
    Column (
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = image,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
        )
        TaskManagerText(
            status = status,
            message = message,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun TaskManagerPreview() {
    TaskManagerTheme {
        TaskManagerImage(status = stringResource(R.string.task_status_text),
            message = stringResource(R.string.task_message_text)
        )
    }
}
```

`strings.xml` is:

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Task Manager</string>
    <string name="task_status_text">All tasks completed</string>
    <string name="task_message_text">Nice work!</string>
</resources>
```

Preview:

[Text composable fails to display Android Compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfdBK.png)

As you can see, it's missing "Nice work!" text.

I've tried changing parameters naming, however that didn't fix it.

Swapping one Text composable with the other will correctly display the text "Nice work!", however, "All tasks completed" will not be rendered.

So it seems second Text composable, whatever that may be, is not rendered.

I don't want to look at the solution until I fix this issue so any hints to resolve it would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting line #84 (`.fillMaxSize()`) and adding it to **modifier** on line #73 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same instance of modifier you receive as a function parameter for multiple elements, as you do in `TaskManagerText`, is wrong. Use the one you receive only for the `Column`, texts should have their own modifiers (`Modifier` instead of `modifier`):

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TaskManagerText(status: String, message: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Text(
            text = status,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top=24.dp, bottom=8.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = message,
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
        )
    }
}
```